# Cant correctly config quality and drift monitors

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio, watson-openscale

I have really strange problem
So, I created model via Modeler Flow using Spark Environment
There was a .csv file, that consists of data about bank's clients 
and this model had to predict is there any risk to give these people the loan.
After that, I deployed the model and get to OpenScale instance.

So the problem is:

When I config the "Model Details" [it ask to point the field from training data file that contains the answers to be predicted by the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfViO.jpg)  
it shows me that there is only one suitable field (and its correct), this field contains string data (I TOTALLY ENSURE IN IT!!)
Then it ask to point the column in the OUTPUT Data from the model [From the output data, select the feature that contains the prediction generated by the AI deployment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFPVU.jpg)

There are three possible columns, two of them have string type and another one is double type
I choose the middle one because this column consists of string predictions values (No/Yes)

Ok, it's done.

Go to quality monitor and it shows me this message [Prerequisites Check has failed: Label column `label` in `training_data_schema` with modelling role `target` has different type `double` than column `$X-Risk` in `output_data_schema` with modelling role `prediction` of type `string`; Verify `label_column` and `prediction_field` settings in `asset_properties` of your subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pulDt.jpg)

I really don't know how to fix it. Because I KNOW that that there is NO column named LABLE and of course there is NO column named LABLE with DOUBLE TYPE!!

Help me please!!

Comment: Also there is another question. Is it possible to create model via Modeler Flow without Spark Environment, and push its deployment into OpenScale with Lite (free) instance?

Comment: Hi @TiHan, do you mean modeler flow using SPSS backend?

Comment: Hi @loremipsum! Yes, I mean, is it real to deploy neural network that was made via SPSS in Openscale? I know that to use SPSS models in OpenScale I need buy Cloud Pak for Data, but I can't even know will it work or not, just don't wanna waste money on it until insurance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created a spark model , you must have done a string indexing while training model this would apply even for the target column (aka label column ) , which might have lead to detecting the target column from training data to be a double column , so please try selecting  the prediction column (that you select from output data) to be the number (aka double column) and it should resolve your problem mostly

Comment: Yes, its work, but drift detection function required both columns (input and output) to be the same type (string or any another).
Thank you for quick answer, I really appreciate